# installing custom npm version with nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I believe that all node versions are going to install a definite version of npm on your system - there is a 1 to 1 relationship between the node version and a npm version.

I am using nvm to install custom versions of node.

But how can I install a version of npm which is not the one - that is bundled with that version of node.

```
nvm install 8.17.0
nvm use 8.17.0
```

the npm version with it is 6.13.4 - But I want to use npm version of 5.6
How can I do that?
Is it possible to find the npm version which comes with various node versions?

Basically for installing the latest npm version is

```
npm install npm@latest
```

but how to do this

```
npm install npm@5.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer:

```
npm install npm@5.6.0 -g
```

Comment: This is not installing it in nvm though.

Comment: Should be: `nvm install 5.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

After installing it with npm, i.e:

```
npm install npm@16.14.2 -g
```

it won't be recognized by nvm:

```
nvm list

    19.1.0
  * 16.18.1 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
```

Only after you install it with nvm:

```
nvm install 16.14.2
```

It will be recognized by nvm:

```
nvm list

    19.1.0
  * 16.18.1 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    16.14.2
```